# Use jQuery to access dynamically made button to show dynamically made content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons and content made dynamically from my database. I need to be able to press a button and have it toggle the content in the associated `<pre>`.

I am able to get jQuery to have click events with each button, but it only shows the content of the most recently created `<pre>`.

I just don't know how to get each button to interact with the correlating `<pre>` tag. Any help would be appreciated.

```php
echo "<div class='my-buttons'>";
for ($j = 0; $j < $num; ++$j)
{
  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo "<button id=title>".$row['title']."</button>";
  $code = base64_decode($row['code']);
  echo "<pre style='display:none' id='code'>$code</pre>";        
}
echo "</div>
```

```js
$('.my-buttons').on('click', (e) => $('#code').slideToggle('slow')))
```

Comment: "Dynamically made" *by php* is not dynamically made.  Your issue is that they all have the same `id=code`, so `$("#code")` will always give you the first one.

Comment: Also for future questions about JS, it's much better to include the actual HTML output instead of the PHP which isn't relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two main issues here. Firstly you apply `id` attributes to the HTML elements you create in your PHP loop. As such, you are duplicating them which is invalid. There can only ever be 1 element in the DOM with a given id. Change these to classes instead.

Then within your jQuery code you need to use DOM traversal to find the `pre` element related to the clicked button, not target all `pre` elements at once. Given the HTML structure you have, `next()` will do this for you:

```js
$('.my-buttons').on('click', e => $(e.target).next('.code').slideToggle('slow'));
```

```css
pre.code { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='my-buttons'>
  <button class="title">title 1</button>
  <pre class="code">Code 1... </pre>
  
  <button class="title">title 2</button>
  <pre class="code">Code 2... </pre>
  
  <button class="title">title 3</button>
  <pre class="code">Code 3... </pre>
  
  <button class="title">title 4</button>
  <pre class="code">Code 4... </pre>
  
  <button class="title">title 5</button>
  <pre class="code">Code 5... </pre>
</div>
```

Also note the use of external CSS to apply the `display: none` to the `pre` elements. Inline styling using the `style` attribute should be avoided where possible as it ties the HTML and CSS together too closely.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamically created/changed element (after DOM loading) you can use following code:

```
$(document).on('click','#exampleID',function(){
//do something
});
```

Comment: I also considered that (and would close vote as a duplicate of [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) ) - but the "dynamically created elements" are not created by js, rather by php (so not "dynamic" as we would term them).  This can be ruled out as OP states *but it only shows the content of the most recently created `<pre>`* (so the click event is fine)